# Azure - generating REST SDKs from IDL

Tags: rest, azure, code-generation

I want to build REST-based web services on Microsoft Azure. I want to define my web service APIs using some kind of IDL from which client SDKs for various programming languages can be generated. Ideally, even client documentation, test code, and client sample code could be generated.

Outside the Azure world, there are tools like Swagger and RAML that attempt to do this. Does anyone know of an equivalent, existing or planned, in the Azure space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is coming very soon - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/10/23/microsoft-acquires-apiphany.aspx.